# How many sockets will be used in a GET request

Tags: java

How many sockets will be used in a GET request.
This is asked in an interview

Comment: Server-side? Client-side? Both?

Comment: Can two people communicate using one phone?

Comment: The answer depends on the precise question that was asked.  And I'm sure that that was not the precise question :-)

Comment: How many proxies are between the client and server?

Answer (score 3):

If that was the exact phrasing of the question, I would ask a clarifying question (probably expected) - following Arkadiy's comment - server-side, client-side, or both?  Also, we are talking about HTTP GETs, right?

Another thing that the interviewer might be looking for is how this could differ between a simple, single GET request (using a tool like curl) - and a full-fledged web browser, where multiple connections (sockets) will be opened in order to concurrently download several portions of the page content (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) at once (rather than all sequentially).